# Interpretation of Geometric Average when Translating Statistics to Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

- The arithmetic average of samples (instances of the random variable) gives an idea of the true expectation of the random variable distribution (the first moment of the distribution).
- Does the geometric average also tell something about the distribution of a random variable?

Comment: The first statement is based on the result that the Law of Large Number tell us that the sample mean (arithmetic mean) is a consistent estimator of the true mean and the Central Limit Theorem also help us to draw some asymptotic inference around the point estimator. Now the geometric mean is $\displaystyle \left(\prod_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^{1/n} = \exp\left\{\frac {1} {n} \sum_{i=1}^n \ln X_i \right\}$, so using the same rationale, the geometric mean can help you estimate $\exp\{E[\ln X]\}$

Comment: @BGM Assuming the Central Limit Theorem is applicable only to normal distributions the first statement holds only for normal distributions. Could it be that for some distributions the expectation is calculated using the geometric mean?

Comment: @BGM your comment is already a complete answer. OP: the geometric mean is related to the expectation of the log only. The reason that it is important is that for distributions that are skew over several orders of magnitude, the expectation of the log is frequently (but not always) the more valuable estimator.